# Tracking the libraries and scripts that a website uses

Tags: javascript, image-processing, three.js

I upload STL files to a website called Thingiverse.com then it automatically creates a preview of 3D design files.
I am interested in learning which libraries does website use.
For instance for this page: https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:2405615 
When I click on Thingview and then take a look at the source code of the page I see that it uses:

```
<script src="/thingiview/js/three.min.js?v=2"></script>
<script src="/thingiview/js/Thingiview.js?v=2"></script>
<script src="/thingiview/js/NormalControls.js?v=2"></script>
<script src="/thingiview/js/Detector.js?v=2"></script>
<script>
        var target_dom_element = $('.thingiview').get(0);

        // parse opts
        var argv = {};
        var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function(m,key,value) {
            argv[key] = value;
        });

        var thingiview = new Thingiview( target_dom_element, 628, 472 );
        if ( parseInt(argv['width']) && parseInt(argv['height']) )
            thingiview.resize( parseInt(argv['width']), parseInt(argv['height']) );

        var animate = function() {
            requestAnimationFrame( animate );
            thingiview.render();
        }
        animate();

        // handle resizes
        window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
            if ( thingiview.fullscreen )
                thingiview.resize(window.innerWidth, 608);
        });

    </script>
```

However, when I click on the Thingview button, the visual angle of the image changes and also shadows and lightings on image disappear. I am particularly interested in finding the script that creates these shadows and lightings in the STL file.
Is there a way of finding how Thingiverse creates previews of design files? I need to take the snapshot of design files from the same angles and with same effects

Answer (score 1):

`three.js` allows for 3d objects to be displayed in browsers. It looks like STL files can be directly loaded into it. They have an [example](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/js/loaders/STLLoader.js) in their github repo. I would image when you upload a file it gets passed to `three.js` and then it is displayed. All of the shadows and visuals should be handled by the library.

Comment: So is there a deafult setting for shadows and visuals?

Comment: In other words, it optimizes both the angle of the image and visuals autamatically ?

Comment: I'm not sure "default" is the right word. Shadows and visuals are handled by three.js, but there is some amount of configuration and tweaking that would be neccesary before anything looks like Thingiverse. [Here](http://learningthreejs.com/blog/2012/01/20/casting-shadows/) is a link to a tutorial for adding shadows in three.js.

Comment: I see, I am seeking for those configurations and tweakings. Because Thingiverse somehow automatize the optimization. And I need that exact optimization

Comment: If I understand you correctly, I can not see what exactly Thingiverse does? Right?

Comment: Everything that is on the front end / webgl is visible. You can get the entire source code, as well as inspect the draw calls / shaders.

Comment: The thing below the model looks like some super wonky weird reflection, not a shadow.

Comment: Use the debugging tools in chrome/firefox/safari. Inspect the canvas / shaders. Step through the code. Unminify, and inspect. It's definitely not a trivial task and you do need to know js.

Answer (score 1):

I think it uploads STL files to cloud and only there it creates the previews. I am not sure whether you can see what is going on there. What do you think @pailhead ?